# What goes into the design of lightsaber hilts?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, jedi

Certain lightsaber hilts look as though the were designed awkwardly. Namely, Darth Vader's and Luke Skywalker's (ROTJ) hilts have a box-like section that would make gripping it difficult.

In [Wookieepedia: Lightsaber hilt Assembly section](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber_hilt#Assembly),

> Nearly every lightsaber hilt was unique in its construction, borne of the Force-user who created it and using whatever materials were at hand; typically, such weapons were created over a span of months. Ideally, the Jedi or Sith who created it would go into deep Meditation, poring over each individual component to be added and thus forging a connection with it through the Force.

But considering that Darth Vader and ROTJ Luke Skywalker both had robotic hands, maybe these box-like sections serve a purpose. *Is this a coincidence?* When Luke's robotic hand was constructed at the end of ESB, it looked like a normal human hand. I don't see what function these uncomfortable box-like piece would have in a grip of a sword-like weapon.

[image: Various lightsaber grips]

Comment: They're actually iPod docks. It's so Vader/Luke can hook their saber up to their nano and kill people to their favorite jams. Later lightsabers would incorporate built-in MP3 players, but it looks like Adi Gallia had to settle for a crappy AM/FM radio tuner.

Comment: I don't understand why the label for Yoda's says "Jedi Master Yoda TPH (Not seen in TPM)." Why the paradox?

Comment: talking about the lightsaber? find it funny that lightsaber is yellow though, did Lucas change his mind in AOTC to make it green?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris I'm guessing they were produced for merchandising, despite not appearing in the film.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lightsaber does not require excessive force to wield.  Even a small child could swing one easily.  Therefore, two-handed grips aren't needed (excepting Darth Maul's double-bladed weapon) for simple swinging, just for fancy maneuvers.  The second hand helps control the blade, and for this a looser grip is better.  This is likely why the second hand's position can have such difficult to hold grips - they may be used to better control the blade.

It's also possible they are used to more easily fit into charging stations (the novel *I, Jedi* mentions that lightsabers are recharged similarly to how blaster power packs are charged).

There is nothing about their mechanical limbs which requires this feature, nor does it interface with them in any meaningful way.

Each lightsaber was, indeed, custom made after a long design process.  That said, there are definite styles that people follow, typically mimicking their Master (or the Jedi who instructed them in lightsaber construction) or a Jedi who's style they wanted to follow.

Comment: "The lightsaber does not require excessive force to wield."  By itself, yes.  But when you're pushing against the blade of another Jedi (especially a Sith), it would require a great deal of force (and, especially, torque).

Comment: Director Richard Marquand, while working on "Return of the Jedi," said that he felt Irvin Kershner had missed the point in a few scenes in "The Empire Strikes Back" and had people operating lightsabers with one hand and said (slightly facetiously), "Everyone knows it takes two hands to handle a light saber."

Comment: @TangoOversway: Yes, but that's not necessarily because they're hard to swing, just hard to control.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes.  I wasn't trying to be argumentative -- just providing that piece of info for what it's worth.

Comment: @TangoOversway I always thought that was one of the best subtle points about ESB - Darth Vader starts his fight by happily batting Luke away one handed, and by the end of it is two-handed and having to put in real effort.  Thus showing the progression of Luke's skills as he goes through his ordeal.

Comment: I think it's now considered Legends, but one of the explanations given for why combat looked like lightsabers had blade weight (also to explain why non-Force users couldn't just pick one up) was a "gyroscopic effect" which either made it hard to start a lightsaber moving or made it hard to stop once in motion. That said, it was never really well-explained, and the "gyroscopic effect", I think, was named more for the analogy of trying to move a spinning gyroscope than that it worked exactly like one.